# iOS 4.x devices coverage

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, system

Does anyone know any estimates of iOS 4 and later update coverage of iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad devices?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What percentage of iPhone users have the different versions of iPhone OS/firmware?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021929/what-percentage-of-iphone-users-have-the-different-versions-of-iphone-os-firmware)

Comment: That question was closed because "This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet." But even though I think is useful and better than having no info about it. Like a wiki to see how things are... I don't think is a good Idea to close this question too, at least not too soon.

Comment: Nacho4d, that's what Wiki's are for. Stack Overflow isn't a wiki. Not convinced this question would suffice as a Community Wiki either. The information is available but it is forever changing, so anything answered here will be out of date very quickly, probably inaccurate and will be misleading for the most part. I don't think this is good question for Stack Overflow. Elsewhere, maybe.

Comment: @nacho4d - As Jasarien points out, this is a problematic question for Stack Overflow, which is why it keeps getting asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72954/how-do-we-deal-with-a-recurring-question-like-os-install-base-statistics

Comment: I got the point, isn't a "community wiki" or something like that here? I have never used but Actually I thought of a place like that for these kind of questions instead of closing them for ever.

Answer (score 2):

Flurry Analytics is telling me that 91.9% of the 12k sessions done on my news app are on iOS4+.

Comment: And in around 6 - 8 months this information will be inaccurate or no longer true. Will you keep coming back to update your answer as these stats change? I'm not attacking your answer, Tahoe, just making a point as to why these types of question aren't a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ya, I'm not going to update it as things change.  In the end, this is what I figured was the desired response to the question.  Part of posting on any sort of forum is the time stamp which allows readers in the future to get context on the post.  To play devils advocate, wouldn't most of the Apple related answers on Stack Overflow be bad because of their ability to be made trivial or false by an update by Apple?