# Are there many devices around with early iOS Versions?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am to decide wether to use a comfortable function that was introduced with iOS 3.2 versus a rather complicated implementation that works fine with older versions too.

3.2 does not run on first generation devices.

Are there any statistics available that tell you how much of a potential market is excluded by setting iOS 3.2 as a minimum requirement?

Comment: This depends on lots of other factors that you don't talk about, such as which devices you're targeting, whether you have an existing app/install base, etc. The fact is, the correlation between 3.1 (and older) devices and people who are likely to take a new or updated app is very small, and can probably be ignored. But again, subject to your situation and goals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 4.x devices coverage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606430/ios-4-x-devices-coverage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: stats]
<sub>(source: [jcmultimedia.com.au](http://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Table2-iOS-Versions-One-Week.png))</sub>

There you go. Basically, everyone uses 4.x. Nothing to fret about.

[This is the link.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170725181007/http://blog.jcmultimedia.com.au:80/2011/03/is-it-worth-supporting-ios-3-in-2011.html)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Where did you get that from? 
How many of those 11% may be below 3.2?

Comment: Sorry about that, right away.

Answer (score 1):

This article has some good, recent stats:

http://www.marco.org/2011/08/13/instapaper-ios-device-and-version-stats-update

There's also another SO question for this - [How many units of each iOS version are currently in usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242606/how-many-units-of-each-ios-version-are-currently-in-usage) - but it's kinda old.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

There are no general, one-size-fits-all set of statistics. Mobile ad providers usually collect and publish them, but that just tells you about the people who use ad supported apps. Individual app developers might collect them and even share them, but that just tells you about who buys their app. And so on. Any stats you find will be of some subset of the population.

Even if you could get the exact number of devices out there running each version of iOS, it wouldn't really be a good answer to your question, because you're interested in them as a potential market, not just as a number of people.

And on the other side, supporting older iOS versions comes at an increased cost in your development and support time.

In other words, you need to sell enough copies of your app to iOS 3.x users to make it worth the extra time it takes doing things the hard way.

Most of the time, it is rarely worth it. Except in cases where you are selling to schools who only upgrade once every ten years, most users who buy software are going to keep their devices up to date. The rest are people who don't like to mess with their devices. Maybe they installed the free Facebook app, but they aren't going to buy your app.

So forget about them. You can sell to them in two years when they buy a new phone.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Yes, the cost and time factor is the driver here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say approximately 0%. Don't bother with gen-1 devices.

Comment: Well, I know some. Therefore nearly 0% cannot be right. But even if you were right, this does not give an answer to the question for any available statistics.

Comment: @Hermann: You knowing some, and "approximately 0%" are not mutually exclusive. I've been doing iPhone development solidly for a couple of years now, and I have a reasonable grasp of the scene. I was going to append some further advice about what to target, but it doesn't come in the form of a table or graph, so I guess you're not interested.